# WSO2 API Manager Convert JSON REST API to SOAP/WSDL on the backend

Tags: json, soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have deployed REST API in API Manager and I need to request this API as REST API (already done) and as SOAP/WSDL endpoint (for some clients).

Do you now any solution for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send SOAP body as a REST (POST) call, you can create an API giving a SOAP endpoint. For that you should follow `Add New API -> I have a SOAP endpoint` in Publisher.

If you want to send a json and convert it to SOAP before sending to backend, you can [follow this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Convert+a+JSON+Message+to+SOAP+and+SOAP+to+JSON).

Comment: I haven't SOAP endpoint. I want to send a SOAP and convert it to REST before sending to backend (reverse to article, that you added).

Comment: You can't do that with APIM. APIM can only expose REST APIs. You can use `Proxy Services` in ESB for that. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Adding+a+Proxy+Service